# SSRS DataSet doesn't seem to update when depending on parameter

Tags: sql-server, url, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

> **The issue**:

I'm working on a SSRS report, but have encountered some quite strange behavior when I populate a **DropDown** (another paramter, named **"Group"**) using a DataSet that uses another parameter that is passed in through the URL.

The problem is that I want the Group-parameter to be updated from the URL parameter **TrackerTypeID**, which works absolutely fine in other cases. Though this is the first time I have a parameter depending on another parameter in its DataSet.

However if I have **TrackerTypeID** as a visible parameter and manually change the integer value of the parameter the DropDown parameter (Group) is updated accordingly.

> **What I've done:**

So I have a hidden parameter that is passed in through the URL called **TrackerTypeID**. This parameter is then used in the ***where-clause*** of the DataSet that populates another parameter:

```
SELECT 

ID,
TrackerGroupDescription

FROM 

vw_TRK_TrackerGroup_LK

WHERE
TrackerTypeID = @TrackerTypeID

Union SELECT Null, '-- Select All --'
```

As you may suspect it uses the **`Available Values`** in Parameter properties to set the available values from a query.

> **What I expect to happen:**

As you might have already suspected I wish for the DropDown parameter to be

Comment: Have you checked the ordering of the parameters?  Any parameters that depend on others need to go after the parent parameter.  So TrackerTypeID probably needs to sit at the top as its linked to the dataset.

Comment: SSRS is smart like that as it doesn't even allow you to save the report if those conditions aren't met. Ie. you can't save the report if you have a parameter that is dependent on another parameter with the dependent parameter above the dependency.

Comment: You have other reports requiring a specific set of parameters? I remember where I was in an environment where nothing apparent prevented me from adding parameters, but because of how the groups of reports were linked, modifying the report parameter would break SSRS. Long story short: Create a parent report, embed the current report (with the same amount of parameters as the other reports) and go from there.

Comment: What you're doing all seems correct. I think we'll need more details to spot the problem. I would start with the dataset properties -> Parameters tab. I would display the hidden parameter value on the report to confirm its value. Turn off caching if applicable. And then go from there.

Comment: Also check in the Report Parameter Properties -> Advanced -> Always Refresh. By default this will be set to Auto which 'should' work but worth trying to force it to always refresh.